# Does the number of expected users affect optimal pool size in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, connection-pooling

I have a rails application that will be used by 17 people simultaneously. Should I set the pool to 17?

Comment: What pool you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should set it much lower. The users won't spend all of the time running database queries, and in the time when the database connection is idle, it can be used for other users.

That's what connection pooling is all about, that and avoiding lots of connects and disconnects.

Of course the number of concurrent application users influences the connection pool size, but it shouldn't be the same.